# Reload Tomcat webapp automatically?

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection

Is it possible to configure web.xml to reload a specific tomcat webapp at a particular time automatically. If not, is it possible to do this programatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programatically - an option is to write an Ant script for reload the webapp you want based on the example [given on the Tomcat docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html#Executing_Manager_Commands_With_Ant)

So you'll be left with a command like

```
ant -Dpassword=secret reload
```

and put this into a cron tab on your server (if Unix/Linux) or Windows Task Scheduler for windows.

I notice you've tagged your question `garbage-collection`. If you are redeploying the web app due to excessive GC, then its better to tackle the root cause of the issue since this reload is only a workaround.

Run a profiler to identify memory leaks.

**Related Reading on Memory Issues / GC**

[Java memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638011/java-memory-leak)

[When log shows a lot of GC hits, what code change shall we need?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847138/when-log-shows-a-lot-of-gc-hits-what-code-change-shall-we-need/2847281#2847281)

[Ways to reduce memory churn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077154/ways-to-reduce-memory-churn/3077857#3077857)

Comment: Points for mentioning that the problem is to be solved somewhere else. Keeping reloading it makes no sense.